# Output of 50 - broken up to 10 numbers per line

Tags: java

I am struggling trying to find a way to output this array/loop so that only 10 outputs appear on a line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double [] alpha = new double[50];        
    int num=1;                             

    for (int i=0; i < alpha.length; i++) {   
        alpha[i] = num;                     //populate index 0-50 w/ 1-50
        num++;

        if (alpha[i] < 26)                            // first 25, print ^2
            System.out.print(Math.pow(alpha[i],2)+ "  ");        
        else                                     // last 25, print value(3)
            System.out.print(alpha[i]*3 + "  ");              
   }
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a conditional that prints a break line if `i + 1` is multiple of `10`.

```
for (int i=0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
    //your code here...
    if ( (i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it could be to iterate over the lines u want to print:

```
// Get the total number of lines you want
int lines = len(alpha) % 10;

for (int i=0; i < lines; i ++) {
    for (int j = i * lines; j < i * lines + 10; j++) {
        // Print the modified alpha[j]
        System.out.print(alpha[j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```